# What's the equivalent of "set macligatures" (macvim) for gvim?

Tags: vim

I recently switched from Mac OSX to Linux and I'd like to keep ligature fonts in gVim.

On Mac I could use MacVim with

```
set macligatures
```

What's the equivalent for gVim?

Comment: Check this [link](https://laracasts.com/series/vim-mastery/episodes/4) it suggests `:set guifont=Monaco:h16` maybe that could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For gVim it's not necessary to set macligatures.

Comment: Nevertheless, I can't get ligatures to work for me all the time. eg. ligatures show up only I open vimdiff and only in the diff hunks itself.